# Python Pandas: Encountered Error with interpolate cubic

Tags: python

I am testing out the interpolate by cubic, but I get below error:

**TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**

```
import pandas as pd
q = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], index=pd.period_range('2018-01-01',freq='Q', periods=20))

m2 = q.resample('M').interpolate(method='cubic')
```